# How to automatically add contacts to a group that matches the ACL?

Tags: 4.7, acl, user-experience

I've got ACLs set up. Certain users can only have access to contacts in a particular group.

The problem is that when this user creates a contact they have to remember to add the contact to that group, otherwise they cease having permission to view/edit that contact the moment it's created.

Obviously this is clearly *their fault*, but realistically it's going to be a real paper cut in the system, leading to frustration and also lots of duplicate contacts as they just try again with a new contact.

I'm thinking of writing some code that either automatically adds contacts created into an appropriate group based on the user's access groups, or some hacky javascript thing that pops up a *"Oh, you've not added them to a group - did you forget?"* confirmation message.

But I suspect this problem's been found before and possibly dealt with a different/better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I didn't hear from anyone, I figured I'd just write the extension.

[Artful Robot's AutoGroup Extension](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.autogroup) is here for your delight and delectation.

From the README:

> This extension allows you to choose a set of groups which will be added to new contacts if the logged in contact is also in that group.
>
> e.g. If Staff member Wilma is in the group 'Region: Birmingham' and Wilma adds a new contact, it can automatically add the new contact into 'Region: Birmingham'
> group.

Comment: interesting. thx for sharing